# Zend Framework 2 And mySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

My situation is that I have data to be added in two tables Login and Customer Details in MySQL. The data is being collected by Zend Framework 2 one form and being added into Database at the same time. Both Tables in MySQL has a Customer_ID. In both table the customer_id is Auto increment.I want to it to be such that when add the data via the form the Customer_ID in Customer Details is auto incremented and its value is copied onto the Login table Customer_ID.

So far I have tried it with LastInserverValue(), I have tried making Login's Customer_ID a FK, I have tried to manually assign the customer_ID to Login with no luck.
With the above methods I used they only added but Customer_ID are not the same.

Note: The data is being added not Updated.

UPDATE: I know I can get using last insert ID but because I am using two tablegateways for the two tables in ZF2 i cant figure out how to get the last insert value from tablegateway1 to tablegateway 2

Answer (score 0):

Your auto increment should only be on the Customer table. You may also have an auto increment for the login id on the login table, but you're quite right to have the login.customer_id a foreign key.

In the login process you want to get the customer.customer_id then create an insert into the login table

E.g Structure:

**Customer**

customer_id INT PK, AI

first_name

last_name

username

password

**Login**

id PK, AI

customer_id (FK) customer.customer_id

created_at

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer. But how can I get the customer.customer_Id when all the values are getting update together. I know I can get using last insert ID but because I am using two tablegateways for two tables in ZF2 i cant figure out how to get the last insert value from tablegateway1 to tablegateway 2.

Comment: So is this more of a register form than a login form?

Answer (score 0):

> In both table the customer_id is Auto increment

First remove the auto increment for customer_id from another table LOGIN.
the insert values in Customer Table using tablegateway1 and get the last insert value
now update this value in Login table for customer_id using table gateway2.

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Paul Sellars, if you will remove AI from one table, then your problem will be solved. In the table, where AI is defined, insert the data into their first and and get last_insert_id from there. With that value, update/insert the record into the other table where AI is not defined.